# After importing mySql database i have Strange Characters in database text: Ã, Ã, ¢, â‚ €

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have export database for multilanguage website  and re-import it,and i have Strange Characters for arabic and japanese languages, i have tried many solutions to fix it but without a good result.
Now when i add a new post in arabic or japanese languages it's working fine, but i see Strange character appearances in old posts.

My database :

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Client: localhost:3306
-- G√©n√©r√© le: Mar 05 Avril 2016 √† 19:18
-- Version du serveur: 5.5.48-cll
-- Version de PHP: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pm_videos`;
CREATE TABLE `pm_videos` (
  `id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniq_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `video_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `yt_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `yt_length` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `yt_thumb` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `yt_views` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `submitted_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submitted` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastwatched` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `added` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `site_views` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url_flv` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `source_id` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `language` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `age_verification` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_check` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `featured` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `restricted` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allow_comments` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `allow_embedding` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `video_slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uniq_id` (`uniq_id`),
  KEY `added` (`added`),
  KEY `yt_id` (`yt_id`),
  KEY `featured` (`featured`),
  KEY `submitted_user_id` (`submitted_user_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_index` (`video_title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Contenu de la table `pm_videos`
--

INSERT INTO `pm_videos` (`id`, `uniq_id`, `video_title`, `description`, `yt_id`, `yt_length`, `yt_thumb`, `yt_views`, `category`, `submitted`, `lastwatched`, `added`, `site_views`, `url_flv`, `source_id`, `language`, `age_verification`, `last_check`, `status`, `featured`, `restricted`, `allow_comments`, `video_slug`, `allow_embedding`) VALUES
(7999, 'bd21476c6', 'ÿ®ŸÉÿßÿ° ÿßÿ®ŸÜ ŸÉŸäÿ±ÿßŸÜ ÿ®ÿ¨ŸÜÿßÿ≤ÿ© ÿπÿ®ÿØ ÿßŸÑŸÑŸá ÿ®Ÿáÿß', '', '', 0, 'bd21476c6-1.jpg', 0, '8', 'mohamed', 1456351954, 1455803880, 96, '1360bf2b.mp4', 1, 1, '0', 0, 0, '0', '0', '1', '%d8%a8%d9%83%d8%a7%d8%a1-%d8%a7%d8%a8%d9%86-%d9%83%d9%8a%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%86-%d8%a8%d8%ac%d9%86%d8%a7%d8%b2%d8%a9-%d8%b9%d8%a8%d8%af-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%84%d9%87-%d8%a8%d9%87%d8%a7', '1'),
(8000, 'a1f3adea0', 'Real Madrid 4 - 0 PFC Ludogorets Razgrad All Goals and Full Highlights', '', '', 0, 'a1f3adea0-1.jpg', 0, '11', 'mohamed', 1457028724, 1455803880, 94, 'dcccc4c0.mp4', 1, 1, '0', 0, 0, '0', '0', '1', 'real-madrid-4-0-pfc-ludogorets-razgrad-all-goals-and-full-highlights', '1'),

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: This is usually caused by the file encoding when exporting.

Comment: provide more details please !!@scottevans93

Answer (score 2):

You probably changed characters encoding. There are many types of encoding such as UTF-8 or Latin-1 which define how the character will be converted in bits (0101001...).

If data is not encoded the same way that your mysql thinks it is, mysql won't understand it and will display weird characters.

Some ways exist to convert data encoding in your database using the CLI.
First you need to find out which encoding you want for your db, you can find a list [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html).
Then, you need to change data encoding : there is a well explained tutorial to do so [here](https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8)